# Advise on hinge type for face frame cabinet making

Tags: cabinetry, door, hinges

im making a cabinet (not the tradition type). 
I will need a hinge for face frame type, with fully inset doors, and the frame and the door will only be 3/4". plus i only have 2 1/4" of space from the edge of the frame to the side walls.

here is an image to help imagine what im talking about, and with the actually measurements like i have above.

[image: Pic]

Comment: [Blum inset face frame hinges](http://www.rockler.com/blum-soft-close-110-blumotion-inset-clip-top-hinges-for-face-frame-cabinets); received mixed reviews.

Comment: (See also http://www.contractortalk.com/f13/hinges-use-face-framed-full-inset-cabinet-door-application-126979/ and http://www.contractortalk.com/f13/flush-inset-door-hinging-options-56961/)

Comment: @JasonC Sounds like an answer to me.

Comment: 2.25" is plenty of space for blum hinges or similar.

Comment: @Matt Except I don't know what I'm talking about and I don't want to just post a Blum ad or misleading advice. In those threads I see some other "euro style" option that mounts to the wall that I also don't understand enough to present. You (or anybody) are welcome to snipe those links for a real answer, though. I just searched Google for "hinge for inset door on face frame" and made sure the pictures looked like the OP's.

Answer (score 2):

The correct choice is an inset face frame hinge. An example hinge can be seen [here](http://www.rockler.com/blum-soft-close-110-blumotion-inset-clip-top-hinges-for-face-frame-cabinets), and the following is an explanation of the different terms:

- **Inset** means the door is inside of the cabinet instead of on the front of the cabinet
- **Face frame** designates that the hinge will be attached to the face frame, as opposed to Euro style hinges which are attached to the side of the cabinet
- The **degrees** listed describe how far the door will swing open
- **Soft close** means there's a cushion or spring inside of the hinge that will prevent the door from slamming

Doors and hinges are one of the more complicated aspects of woodworking and building. Referencing an installation guide before making the final selection is always a good choice. These are often located on the product page but can also be found in the support section of the manufacturers website. For example, the installation guide for the Blum hinge linked above is listed under "Technical Downloads" but can also be found [here](http://www.blum.com/us/en/02/90/).

Answer (score 0):

We hang hundreds of inset faceframe doors a year.  If the space between the inside edge of your faceframe and the wall of your cabinet is less than 5/8, you will have to use the euro-box frameless plates, as opposed to the "castles" (that's what we call them :) ) pictured above.

[Blum Frameless Plates](https://www.build.com/blum-175h9160/s96505?uid=1672799&gclid=CjwKEAjwh9PGBRCfso2n3ODgvUcSJAAhpW5oLpJ8EVGRngw0KK-2uvNo6Yk4TBH5jmdPTLs-74tpExoC3wTw_wcB&source=gg-gba-pla_1672799____78027640639&s_kwcid=AL!4215!3!78027640639!!!g!337170516437!&cawelaid=120135390007909471&cagpspn=pla&caagid=21076242679&catci=pla-337170516437&lsft=source%3Agg-gba-pla_1672799)

If you have to use the frameless plates, you have to build out the distance from the wall of the cabinet to the inside edge of the faceframe.

Tip:  If you can leave the back off your cabinet until after you install those "castles" you will be waaaay happier. There is a center screw hole that is absolutely necessary and a real booger to get to - especially when you wear trifocals...